# button, text field, text area in processing

Tags: processing

Is there any simple library to get gui functionalities like text fields, text areas in processing? . I have written a pong game in processing and I want text fields to get the name of the players.
In the code below I wanted a text field to get names from the players
here is my code

```
            int butt=0;
            float velx=-2;
            float vely=-2;
            float x=350,y=200;

            int s=150;
            int score1=0,score2=0;
            float speed = 1;
            float speed_cont = 0.0001;

            void setup(){
              size(700,400);
              smooth();
              background(100,200,100);
            }

            void draw(){
                stroke(255);
                strokeWeight(15);
                fill(100,100,200);

                rect(175,100,340,100);
                fill(255);
                textSize(38);

                text("CLICK TO PALY",200,160);
                fill(0);
                textSize(30);

                text("Done By BOBO(TARUN GOVIND KESHAV)",50,300);
                textSize(18);
                text("mail: tarun.83581@gmail.com",50,330);
                noStroke();

                if (mousePressed && (mouseButton == LEFT)) {
                  butt=1;
                }

                if(butt==1){
                  background(210);
                  textSize(32);

                  text("score :", 100,30);
                  text(score1,300,30);
                  text(":",400,30);
                  text(score2,500,30);

                  x = x+velx*speed;
                  y = y+vely*speed;
                  speed = speed +speed_cont; // speed control value

                  if(x<=75){
                      x=350;y=200;score2+=1;
                  }
                  if((x>=625)){
                      x=350;y=200;score1+=1;
                  }
                  if((x<=80)&(y>s)&(y<(s+80))){ 
                      velx = -velx;
                  }
                  if((y>=380)||(y<=20)){
                      vely = -vely;
                  } 
                  if((x>=620)&(y>mouseY)&(y<(mouseY+80))){
                      velx = -velx;
                  }

                  ball(x,y);
                  slider(s);
                  slider1(mouseY);
                  }
            }
            void ball(float x,float y){
              fill(0);
              arc(x,y,40,40,0,2*PI);
            }

            void slider(int y){
              fill(200,100,100);
              rect(20,y,40,80);
            }

            void keyPressed(){
             if(keyCode == UP){s=s-15;}
              if(keyCode == DOWN){s = s+15;}
            }

            void slider1(int y){
              fill(200,100,100);
              rect(640,y,40,80);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the processing.org website there are 3 GUI libraries listed on the libraries page (https://processing.org/reference/libraries/)

I've worked with http://www.sojamo.de/libraries/controlP5/ before, it's not to hard to get running I will cover your needs.